# Raising internal floor - to screed or not to screed?

Tags: concrete, floor, plaster, porch, engineered-flooring

The porch of our home has been made part of the interior. We now need to raise the floor to meet the level of the existing floor internally.

[image]

[image]

The total height of the step is 5cm. So the floor needs to be raised 5cm.

I am not sure if the floor needs to be screeded. The carpenter says he can lay some celotex thermal insulation and then pack it out. He says if we do this, he can install the new wooden floor straight away.

The other option is that we have to wait for the floor to be screeded, and wait for the screed to dry. That means we have to wait 1 - 2 months for the new wood floor can be fitted.

Should I just wait longer and wait for a plasterer to screed the floor, or is the carpenter's suggestion is an acceptable solution? I am particularly worried about damp.

Comment: It's hard to tell the height difference from your picture, but it seems small. I would venture that a carpenter or flooring professional could manage a smooth enough float job with a hand trowel (is this what you mean by "pack it out"?). An insulating layer is never a bad thing, I guess, but you don't have Celotex under the rest so I'm not sure you need it.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it thanks for your reply. The total height of the step is 5cm. I've added a new picture to clarify. I believe the carpenter wanted to pack it out with chippings so that he didn't have to wait for the new floor to dry out.

Comment: This is confusing - the picture shows a difference of over 10 cm.  What are you doing with the door, which opens inward and won't open once the floor is raised?

Comment: Hi @Mark, that's just the angle of the photo, sorry. I tried give perspective of the level to the first edge which is 3cm and then hoped it would be possible to infer the next level was about the same. It's 3cm to the first level, then another 2 to the highest level so 5cm alotgether.

Also, well spotted about the door. We are having a new front door fitted next week which is being raised to accomodate the new floor level.